# How to place an inline conditional union/self join in lambda expression?

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-4, lambda

How can I write and line union/join statement using lambda if the parameter calls for 2 different type to value from the same field in table, e.q

```
 Etype
-------
 class A
 class B
 class C
```

I am appending query based upon the user selection from form (coming as QS/parameters in mvc 4)

```
public ActionResult Home(string title, string EtypeA)
{
      EtypeA =  (Convert.ToBoolean(EtypeA)) ? "typeA" : null;
      var results = db.EList.Where(p => (title ==null || p.Title.Contains(title)) && 
                                        (EtypeA ==null || p.EtypeA.Contains(EtypeA)))
      ...
}
```

Thing are good so far, but the form have check boxes for Etype filtration so if user wants to see results with Etype A and Etype B, he'll opt both checkboxes and the params will come as

```
public ActionResult Home(string title, string EtypeA, string EtypeB)
```

Now how can I write inline query to join both types of E (employee).
Since EtypeA and EtypeB refers to the values in Etype field I am trying to find them like :

```
 public ActionResult Home(string title, string EtypeA, string EtypeB)
    {
          EtypeA =  (Convert.ToBoolean(EtypeA)) ? "typeA" : null;
          EtypeB =  (Convert.ToBoolean(EtypeB)) ? "typeB" : null;

var results = db.PartnersList.Where(p => (title ==null || p.Title.Trim().ToLower().Contains(title.ToLower())) &&
                                            ((EtypeA == null || p.EType.Contains(EtypeA) || (EtypeB == null || p.EType.Contains(EtypeB))
```

Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: It is not clear how your `EList` items look like. Do they have separate properties (`EtypeA == "typeA"`, `EtypeB == "typeB"`, ...) which you LINQ example implies, or do you have a single property which can hold different values?

Comment: @Groo : There is a single field Etype, which have 3 types of values (typeA, typeB and typeC) and want to && if query is coming to filter all records where Etype is A and B.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is LINQ-to-SQL (of EF) and you have a `IQueryable`, then chaining multiple `Where` methods should result in the same SQL being emitted:

```
// not sure what EList is though
var items = db.EList.AsQueryable(); // or `IEnumerable<T>` ?

if (title != null)
    items = items.Where(i => i.Title.Contains(title));

var typesToFilter = new List<string>();
if (Convert.ToBoolean(EtypeA))
    typesToFilter.Add("typeA");

if (Convert.ToBoolean(EtypeB))
    typesToFilter.Add("typeB");

if (typesToFilter.Count > 0)
    items = items.Where(i => typesToFilter.Any(i.EType.Contains));

// this is where the provider will actually traverse the 
// expression tree, convert it to SQL and execute it:    
var results = items.ToList();
```

Also, if the `EType` always contains exactly one of the values "typeA", "typeB" or "typeC", then you don't have to use `String.Contains`, but rather `List.Contains` (which will emit more efficient SQL):

```
if (typesToFilter.Count > 0)
    items = items.Where(i => typesToFilter.Contains(i.EType));
```

Alternatively, without chaining you could do a larger one-liner:

```
var results = db.EList.Where(p => 
    (title == null || p.Title.Contains(title)) && 
    (typesToFilter.Count == 0 || typesToFilter.Contains(p.EType)));
```

Comment: I have edited the original question please see if it makes sense now.

Comment: I have one more question if you don't mind, what if the i.Etype also contains multiple items for e.g on records have (class A, class B) in this column.

Comment: How are multiple items combined? Using a comma? I.e. `"typeA,typeB"`? Also, does this means this item should be returned only if A and B are checked together, or even if only one of them is checked? As I wrote in the first snippet, if `EType` can contain multiple items, you can use `typesToFilter.Any(p.EType.Contains)` to find if `p.EType` contains any of the strings in `typesToFilter` (even partially).

Comment: yes they are combined by comma, should be returned if either A or B matches the comparing item in typesToFilter.

Comment: I am not sure what's the type of EType, but I presume it's a string? Most likely compiler is unable to infer types properly. What happens if you write it as `typesToFilter.Any(t => i.EType.Contains(t))`?

Comment: This worked, you are a real genius, Thanks for your time, got a blog or twitter where I can follow ?